# AWS DynamoDB get rows sort by (order by) multiple columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless, serverless-framework, amazon-dynamodb-index

I need to get the rows by key (e.g. where status is "Active") but with sorting on multiple columns.

I'm using the pagination that's why I cannot sort the result after fetching it from the DynamoDB. (Just for the information, I'm using the serverless framework)

Expected Output is array of rows sorted (ordered) by multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

In DynamoDB you get "free" lexicographical sorting on the range keys.

When an item is being inserted first its partition is calculated based on the partition key then the item is inserted into a b-tree which keeps the partition lexicographically sorted at all times. This doesn't give you all of the features of SQLs Order By, which is not supported

So if your sort keys look something like this

```
Status#Active#UserId#0000004
```

You can do "*begins_with*" query with `SK = "Status#Active"`

This will give you all of the items that are in active status ordered by the UserId (that has to be zero-padded in order to enforce the lexicographical order).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Sorting can be only done on SK under the same PK. You could combine multiple columns into one value and query based on it. Something like `column1-value1#column2-value2`.

In that case you'll probably have issue in updating that field, dynamodb streams could help with it. You can trigger event on any modification and asynchronously update that sorting field.